# Compute entropy for continuous values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, entropy

I want to compute entropy for two matrices (inputs). I want the output entropy still using having the matrix shape.

For example::

```
import numpy as np
def entropy(x, y):
   probs = np.mean((x, y), axis=0)  
   p = probs.astype(np.float32) 
   return (-p * np.log2(p))


inp1 = np.random.random([5,4])
inp2 = np.random.random([5,4])

inp1_flatt = inp1.reshape([-1])
inp2_flatt = inp2.reshape([-1])


combine_out = entropy(inp1_flatt, inp2_flatt).reshape([5,4])
```

In the `entropy()` function, I think I have a problem with computing the posterior probabilities (probs).

How can I compute the posterior probabilities in the correct way ?

**EDIT::**

These two inputs suppose to be an regression outputs of Neural Network. I want to save their shape. since the input of the entropy (output of the neural network) has shape [5,4], I want the entropy output shape is [5,4]. I want to do something like combine sources using entropy (**joint entropy method for continuous values**)

Comment: What is the desired output and its shape?

Comment: These two inputs suppose to be an regression outputs. and I want to save their shape. since the input has shape [5,4], I want the output shape is [5,4]. I want to do something like combine sources using entropy

Comment: Your output shape already is `[5,4]`, it is unclear what you are asking. Try and be specific - what's not working?

Comment: I think my question is clear, I write about the posterior probabilities. I want to compute the posterior probabilities in the correct way, then I want to apply the entropy??? I want this for continuous values. Also, I want to save the shape as I used in the code above>
I can not explain more than this